# The nth term of a sequence is given by $T_n=4n-2$. Verify that the sequence is arithmetic

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

The $n$th term of a sequence is given by $T_n=4n-2$. Verify that the sequence is arithmetic.

I have an answer that says the difference is $4$ and that the sequence is arithmetic but the only difference I get is $0$.

Please explain because I've no idea how to get the $T_n+1$ formula in action with the likes of $n(n+2)$.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Can you explain how you get a difference of $0$?  Just write out $T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4$, say.

Comment: I tried a formula with Tn+1, swapped in 4n-2 for 4(n+1)-2 = 4n+4 and then proceeded with Tn+1 + Tn = 4n+2 - 4n-2. I must be doing it wrong :/

Comment: Like I said, just write out the first few values explicitly.  If the differences are always $0$, that means you should get the same value each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your given that the $n$ th term of sequence is:

$$4n-2=T_n$$

So:

$$4(n+1) -2=T_{n+1}=4n+2$$

Now the difference of the $n+1$ th term and the $n$ th term is:

$$T_{n+1}-T_{n}=(4n+2)-(4n-2)$$

$$=4n+2-4n+2$$

$$=4$$

Comment: Ohhhhh, thank you. I see where I made the mistake. Could you also tell me, if the question is Tn=n(n+2) do i have to swap in Tn+1 only for n( or both n's?

Comment: It only logically makes sense if we substitute  it for both $n$'s. If $f(x)=x+x$ then you give me $x$ it gives give you $x+x$ however if you give me $x+1$ it's going to give you $(x+1)+(x+1)$. If you don't quite understand plug in numbers and see why it is necessary to substitute $n+1$ in for everywhere you see an $n$.